# How correctly do a bi-directional many-to-many in nHibernate

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to get my head around how to correctly use many-to-many relationships in NHibernate in DotNet 4.5. What Collection types to use and what to init them as.

Scenario:  Modeling OrgUnits and Positions. There is a many to many relationship with the  following tables:

OrgUnits
Positions
OrgUnitPositions

I'm using bi-directional setters so that no matter if I go orgUnit.AddPosition(position) OR  position.AddOrgUnit(orgUnit), the relationship should be added to both collections.

Here is my example code

```
public class Position 
    {
        public Position()
        {
            OrgUnits = new List<OrgUnit>(); 
        }

        public virtual ICollection<OrgUnit> OrgUnits { get; set; }

        public virtual void AddOrgUnit(OrgUnit orgUnit)
        {
            if (!OrgUnits.Contains(orgUnit))
            {
                OrgUnits.Add(orgUnit);
                if (!orgUnit.Positions.Contains(this))
                    orgUnit.AddPosition(this);
            }
        }


        public class PositionMap : ClassMap<Position>
        {
            public PositionMap()
            {
                    HasManyToMany(x => x.OrgUnits)
                    .ChildKeyColumn("OrgUnitID")
                    .ParentKeyColumn("PositionID")
                    .Table("OrgUnitPositions")
                    .Fetch.Select()
                    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
                    .AsBag()
                    .Inverse();
            }

        }

        public class OrgUnit
        {
            public OrgUnit()
            {
                Positions = new HashSet<Position>();
            }

            public virtual ICollection<Position> Positions { get; set; }

            public virtual void AddPosition(Position value)
            {
                if (!Positions.Contains(value))
                {
                    Positions.Add(value);
                    if (!value.OrgUnits.Contains(this))
                        value.AddOrgUnit(this);
                }
            }
        }
        public class OrgUnitMap : ClassMap<OrgUnit>
        {
        public OrgUnitMap()
        {
            HasManyToMany(x => x.Positions)
            .ChildKeyColumn("PositionID")
            .ParentKeyColumn("OrgUnitID")
            .Table("OrgUnitPositions")
            .Fetch.Select()
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .AsSet()
            ;
        }
    }
```

My problem is that when I call orgUnit.AddPosition(position)), in some circumstancs, this  line in  Position.AddOrgUnit: if (!value.Positions.Contains(this)) returns false, even  though i can see in the debuger that is does contain the org unit. This leads to it being  added twice and then a duplicate key exception occurs on save.

I've tried all sorts of things (my original collections where lists/ILists) but I suspect that my collection type (ilist/iset/etc) is the cause - hoping someone can point me in the  direction of which collection types to use, what to initlise them as, etc.

If I call position.AddOrgUnit(orgUnit); instead of orgUnit.AddPosition, everything works.

--- Update

In response to comments, I changed theAddOrgUnit in Position.cs as follows:

```
public virtual void AddOrgUnit(OrgUnit orgUnit)
    {
        if (!OrgUnits.Contains(orgUnit))
        {
            OrgUnits.Add(orgUnit);
            foreach (Position p in orgUnit.Positions)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", ReferenceEquals(p, this)));
            }

            if (!value.Positions.Contains(this))
            {
                value.AddPosition(this);
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is what i found - keeping in mind that orgUnit.positions only contains 1 item and the for-each is just to get access to that item in the debugger.

ReferenceEquals(p, this) **false**

p.GetHashCode() **40148707**

this.GetHashCode() **53416668**

this.ID **{8386857d-a52e-4f17-8094-a231003299b5}**

p.ID **{8386857d-a52e-4f17-8094-a231003299b5}**

p.Description **"bob"**

this.Description **"bob"**

p.description = "Jane"

this.Description **"Jane"**

p.description **"Jane"**

This is the strange one!  The hashCodes are different, yet it appears to be the same instance of the same object.  IE, if I change a property on the "this" version, it changes in the "p" version.

Finally, 
ReferenceEquals(p.ReportsToPosition, this.ReportsToPosition) **true**

Which tends to indicate they are from the same hibernate session? (ie, the parents are the same)

---

Here is my calling code, we use StrctureMap for IoC, with ISession being injected into the repos.  I have changed my code to pass in the BLL, which guarantees same Isession because the repositories are injected into it.

Strangely, the only line the causes the error is the one indicated, and if I remove lines above, it works perfectly too!

```
[TestMethod]
    public void CreateExampleOrgStructure()
    {
        OrgStructureLogic osl = (OrgStructureLogic)ObjectFactory.GetInstance(typeof(OrgStructureLogic));
        Domain domain = osl.GetNewDomain(DomainTypeEnum.ReportingLines);
        domain.Name = string.Format("blah.Net - {0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString(), DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

        OrgUnit ouGlobal = domain.RootOrgUnit;
        ouGlobal.Name = "Global";

        OrgUnit ouTech = GetNewOrgUnit(ouGlobal, "Technology", osl);
        AddPositionToOrgUnit(ouTech, "Chief Technology Officer", osl);
        AddPositionToOrgUnit(ouTech, "General Manager Technology", osl);

        OrgUnit ouFeatureDevelopers = GetNewOrgUnit(ouTech, "Feature Dev", osl);
        AddPositionToOrgUnit(ouFeatureDevelopers, "Senior Feature Developer", osl);
        AddPositionToOrgUnit(ouFeatureDevelopers, "Feature Developer", osl);

        OrgUnit ouSupportDevelopers = GetNewOrgUnit(ouTech, "Support Dev", osl);
        AddPositionToOrgUnit(ouSupportDevelopers, "Senior Support Developer", osl);
        AddPositionToOrgUnit(ouSupportDevelopers, "Support Developer", osl);

        OrgUnit ouDevManagement = GetNewOrgUnit(ouTech, "Management", osl);
        AddPositionToOrgUnit(ouDevManagement, "Dev Manager", osl); /* This is the problem!!!!*/
        AddPositionToOrgUnit(ouDevManagement, "Application Architect", osl);

        osl.SaveDomain(domain);
    }
```

Even stranger is that I can also fix the problem be changing

```
private void AddPositionToOrgUnit(OrgUnit orgUnit, string positionName, OrgStructureLogic osl)
    {
        orgUnit.AddPosition(GetPositionByName(positionName), osl);
    }
```

to

```
private void AddPositionToOrgUnit(OrgUnit orgUnit, string positionName, OrgStructureLogic osl)
    {       
        Position position = GetPositionByName(positionName, osl);
        position.AddOrgUnit(orgUnit);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try once to compare the Ids of the entities instead of the references? I encountered this kind of problems before, especially when NHibernate generates Proxy-Classes. Sometimes I have overwritten `Equals` (and `GetHashCode`) where I compared the Ids of the entity.

Comment: Can you show the code where you call `orgUnit.AddPosition(position)`?  My guess is that `orgUnit` and `position` are from two different NHibernate sessions.  When you see it in the debugger, could you check to see whether the two instances that you believe to be equal actually do `ReferenceEquals` or not?

Comment: @sl3dg3 I have added the result of the ID comparison - they are the same. I'm hesitant in overwriting Equals/GetHashCode because I like creating graphs of empty objects then saving them by calling save(rootObject) - ie, I want to be able to compare when the objects have a null ID.

Comment: I have tried changing the collections to the IESI ones and have the same problem

Comment: @DanielSchilling - I changed my code to pass through a reference to by BLL which has a reference to my repos - so I don't think it's a different iSession.

Comment: @Dave True, I am also no fan of overwriting equals if the IDs are generated by the database. It is another story though if it is done like http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html?page=1 where the IDs are generated while creating the object. But this won't help you much here I guess...

Answer (score 0):

Following the stack trace down, the value of GetHashCode changes in here:

```
if (!position.OrgUnits.Contains(this))
{
    position.AddOrgUnit(this);
}
```

IE, position.GetHashCode() = "a", but when I step into position.AddOrgUnit, this.GetHashCode() is "b".

Looking at the stack trace,

```
[Native to Managed Transition]      NHibernate.dll!NHibernate.Proxy.DefaultLazyInitializer.Intercept(NHibernate.Proxy.DynamicProxy.InvocationInfo info = {NHibernate.Proxy.DynamicProxy.InvocationInfo}) + 0x14d bytes  
PositionProxyModule.mod!PositionProxy.AddOrgUnit() + 0x1f2 bytes
```

It appears that nHibernate proxies are getting in the way.  Therefore – sl3dg3 is right and the solution is to overwrite Equals & GetHashCode.